# RAID 1 drive showing as Uninitialized in Disk Utility

Tags: hard-drive, raid, disk-utility

I deleted my RAID set by clicking "Delete Raid..." inside of Disk Utility. After that, my drive became like this:

[image: Uninitialized Drive in Disk Utility]

How can I convert this drive back into a normal external hard drive? I have access to both Windows and Mac computers.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, goto Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> Computer Management --> Disk Management.

Right-Click the disk and select 'initialize disk'. Then you can make in in any format you want.

Comment: I don't see it, and in any case I don't see how that will help... will that retain the data?

Comment: You asked how to convert the drive to be usable again, you said nothing about the data. If you deleted the RAID and still want the data on it, use recovery software (like easeus), but you still have to initialize; make sure you select the same type it was before (MBR/GPT).